# Comment text going behind div

Tags: html, css

Got a problem with comments when there are very long words used, like:
"Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis"
Since the comment div is kinda small, it goes behind it.

I guess it is a CSS thing, but I just can't figure out what it is.
When normal words are used, text is formatted correctly, as soon as it gets near the right edge of the div, the new line starts.
But long words simply go behind the right edge of the comment div.

What's the good way to fix this?

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Try `word-wrap: break-word`.

Comment: What do you mean "goes behind"? Please add to the question your HTML and CSS that you're using when you encounter this problem.

Comment: @litel Thanks, it did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making use of the css `word-wrap` property. Specifically, `word-wrap: break-word`.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
            p.test {
                width: 11em; 
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="test"> This paragraph contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Check out [more info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) on this property if you need more expanation.